# How do I target this page specifically?

Tags: customization, themes, css, templates

I have created a Wordpress site, and am looking to hack the template so that I can have a background image at the top of my page (with the menu on top), and for the content of the page to directly beneath it (with the background image behind it, rather than being cut off by the bottom of the header).

I have found a way of doing it using Inspector, however when I put it into my template's .css pages, it doesn't seem to show at all.

I've tried to target the page using the Page ID, .page-id-1715, but it doesn't seem to work. The code I am using is:

```
body.page-id-1715 .default-header-menu-content {
background-image: url(http://www.gps-embroidery.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/biddy-ashton-golf_preview-2.jpeg) !important;
}

body.page-id-1715 .page-column {
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
   margin-top: 200px;
}
```

The page i'm working on can be found at http://www.gps-embroidery.com/embroideries/ashton-court/.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the "template's .css" file? Is it located at wp-content/themes/YOUR_TEMPLATE/style.css?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a CSS override, can't really classify this as a 'hack' ;-)

First, you mentiod you place the css in the theme files, make sure you do it in a child theme, so you can update the theme and don't loose your changes.

More info about child themes [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

When i check your site i see the header background image? Don't forget to clear all browser cache after css changes.

Regards, Bjorn